Как установить новую библиотеку для кода С++
Подскажите пожалуйста как установить библиотеку OpenXLSX в виндовс 10, для использования ее в коде C++ Visual Studio. Есть понимание что ее нужно скачать с GitHub, а потом пишут Настроить проект для работы с этой библиотекой используя CMake или подключив файлы библиотеки вручную И ВОТ ЗДЕСЬ ВООБЩЕ НЕ ПОНЯТЕН ПРИНЦИП КАК ЭТО СДЕЛАТЬ???

Сложность в том, что я всегда использовал англоязычные IDE. В русскоязычных - не имею понятия как называются поля ввода путей расположения и т.п. Обычно, нужно установить путь папки содержащий заголовочные файлы и путь расположения библиотек. Также, если требуется - подключить CPP файлы. На самом деле - это несложно, просто нужно разобраться, раз и навсегда.

В том то и дело что скачиваю openxlsx-master с github в этом архиве нет ни папки includ ни файлов библиотеки lib, а если пытаюсь пойти по пути установить openxlsx через vcpcg там не понятно в каком месте выполнить команду .\vcpkg install openxlsx

Вы неправильно делаете. Сначала нужно прочитать руководство от пользователя (хозяина), тот кто разместил всё Добро. После этого читаем все текстовые Readme - они могут быть без расширения. Я пытаюсь вас настроить на то, что сначала нужно прочитать инструкцию и только затем задавать вопросы. Что ещё? Например, некоторые проекты могут быть интуитивно понятны и включать, чуть ли не Рабочее место для IDE. Если ничего нет. Сомневаюсь, но вполне возможно, что вы наткнулись на что-то недоукомплектованное.
